# MDX Filter & Date Range Issue

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

**Trying to accomplish the following:**

- How many customers purchased from a specific product for any given
  date range
- What were the total sales for customers noted above for any given
  date range

**Current query:
My query below gives me exactly what I want:**

```
    WITH SET Customer_CurrentPeriod as
    FILTER (
    [CUSTOMER MASTER].[Cust#].children ,
    (
    [Calendar].[Date].&[20180507]
    , [Item Master].[Sub Group Number].&[100]
    , [Measures].[Ext Price]
    ) > 0
    )

    member Sales_CurrentPeriod as
    sum (
    ([Customer_CurrentPeriod] , [Calendar].[Date].&[20180507])
    , [Measures].[Ext Price]
    ) 

member Sales_Sum_CurentPeriod_Count as [Customer_CurrentPeriod].Count

SELECT
{Sales_CurrentPeriod , Sales_Sum_CurentPeriod_Count} ON COLUMNS
from [SalesDatabase]
```

**PROBLEM**

When I try to change the date to a date range (code belas shown below I get the error message. Query (4, 6) The GreaterThan function expects a string or numeric expression for the 1 argument. A tuple set expression was used.

```
WITH SET Customer_CurrentPeriod as
FILTER (
[CUSTOMER MASTER].[Cust#].children ,
(
{[Calendar].[Date].&[20180507]:[Calendar].[Date].&[20180507]}
, [Item Master].[Sub Group Number].&[100]
, [Measures].[Ext Price]
) > 0
)

member Sales_CurrentPeriod as
sum (
([Customer_CurrentPeriod] , {[Calendar].[Date].&[20180507]:[Calendar].[Date].&[20180507]})
, [Measures].[Ext Price]
)

member Sales_Sum_CurentPeriod_Count as [Customer_CurrentPeriod].Count

SELECT
{Sales_CurrentPeriod , Sales_Sum_CurentPeriod_Count} ON COLUMNS
from [SalesDatabase]
```

I'm obviously new to MDX so can anyone help figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who has a similar issue - you need to aggregate the field. [How to query Date field in MDX with and without aggregate group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047150/how-to-query-date-field-in-mdx-with-and-without-aggregate-group)